# viewWillDisapper isn't called when opening a second view with popOver

Tags: swift, view, popover, lifecycle

On my mainVC I have a *TableView* with a button that should open the secondVC, *where I can add things to show then in the Table*, with the kind: "Present As Popover".

I'm opening the secondVC with `performSegue(withIdentifier:"goToOtherView", sender: nil`.

```
class FirstViewController: UIViewController {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    
    var groupData = ["Data, Data1, Data2"]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        view.backgroundColor = .green
        
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
        
    }

    @IBAction func btnTapped(_ sender: Any) {
        
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToOtherView", sender: nil)
    }
    
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        print("FirstViewController will appear")
    }
    
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        print("FirstViewController did appear")
    }
    
    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        print("FirstViewController will disappear")
    }
    
    override func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        print("FirstViewController did disappear")
    }
    
}

class SecondViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        view.backgroundColor = .blue

    }
    
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        print("SecoundViewController will appear")
    }
    
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        print("SecoundViewController did appear")
    }
    
    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        print("SecoundViewController will disappear")
    }
    
    override func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        print("SecoundViewController did disappear")
    }
    
}
```

Storyboard[image]

When I start the App [image: When I start the App]

When I open the secondVC [image: When I open the secondVC]

And when I close the secondVC [image]

The FirstViewController `willDisappear` and `didDisappear` are never being called, or even when the secondVC is closed the `willAppear` and `didAppear`. *I want to call the function `tableView.reloadData()` when the FirstView `willAppear`/`didAppear`*

*It's kinda the same like the IOS default clock app, when you add a new alarm clock.*

Comment: Unclear what the issue is. You do not get `disappear` and `appear` unless you (1) push or (2) do a _fullscreen_ presentation. That's no surprise.

Comment: Is there a way to reload the tableView with a push view or do I need to do a fullscreen presentation? I want to reload the data on the tableView with a pushView same as the alarm clock in default IOS apps

Comment: You just need to change the way you detect that the view controller has gone away. For example, if it's a popover, you use the presentation controller delegate methods. Relying on `viewWillAppear` was _always_ a bad idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quick guess, but I think that’s because of the presentation mode being `pageSheet`

Can you try to change it to fullScreen?

You can also change your segue configuration to be like: [image]

View disappear won't be called since the view does not completely disappears from the window

Comment: Thank you for the fast answer and that works with it. I didn't finished my question fully, sorry for the misunderstanding. But thanks for your time!